# SPARQL query for dbpedia to find ski lifts

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm currently trying to teach myself how to formulate SPARQL queries to extract tourism-related information from DBpedia (via http://dbpedia.org/sparql/).

So far, I've managed to get all museums for a country.

```
select ?thing ?type ?category ?long ?lat ?country 
where
  {      
    VALUES ?country { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canada> }

    optional
      { 
        ?city  dbo:country  ?country 
      }

    ?thing  dbo:location  ?city.

    optional
      { 
        ?thing  a  ?type  .
        VALUES ?type { dbo:Museum }
        BIND( 'Museum' as ?category )
      }

    optional
      { 
        ?thing a ?type.
        VALUES ?type { dbo:skiLift }
        BIND( 'Skilift' as ?category )
      }

    optional
      {
        ?thing geo:long ?long.
        ?thing geo:lat ?lat
      }

    {
      ?thing a dbo:Place
    }

    filter (BOUND (?type))
  }
```

However, I don't understand what I need to do to also get the same information for things like `dbo:skiLift`, `dbo:touristicSite` and the like (found here: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't select the variable `typeName`, thus, it should be `BIND( 'Skilift' as ?category )`

Comment: in addition, the public DBpedia endpoint has a default limit of 10000 rows. you won't see the whole result at once. use `OFFSET` to paginate through it

Comment: I've changed the query from "typeName" to "category", but still not getting ski lifts.

Answer (score 2):

This is because both `dbo:skiLift` and `dbo:touristicSite` are properties. These resources show up in the page for Place not as subclasses of Place, but as properties which have the class Place as their domain or range. If you want to find subclasses of Place you can perform the exploratory query (which also uses property path to retrieve the transitive closure of the `subClassOf` property):

```
select ?thing 
where 
  {
    ?thing rdfs:subClassOf+ <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> .
  }
```

Apart from that, I cannot understand why you use two optional clauses for different types in the same query. For example, the following query retrieves museums located at cities of Canada, possibly with their lat and lon, without the use of other optional clauses:

```
select ?thing ?city ?long ?lat  
where
  {
    ?city   dbo:country   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canada> .
    ?thing  dbo:location  ?city .
    ?thing  a             dbo:Museum .

    optional
      {
        ?thing  geo:long  ?long .
        ?thing  geo:lat   ?lat
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and good to know, but I still don't understand how I can get the information for the properties such as dbo:skiLift?

Comment: What information exactly? You can see some triples with a specific property using for example a query like `select ?subject ?object where {   ?subject dbo:skiLift ?object . } LIMIT 10` For the specific property it seems that it is not used in the dataset, so the result is empty.